# Check number of available buffer characters in file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, posix

How do I check how many available characters there in the buffer in a socket file descriptor?

I want to postpone reading bytes from a socket until at least 8 bytes are available (for the length of the following message). I am using `select()` to wait for incoming data. When the read handler for a socket is called, I want it to just return without reading if less than 8 bytes are available.

Will the socket ever even be readable but only for less than 8 bytes?

Is there a Linux system call which can retrieve how many bytes are available to be read from a socket without actually reading them?

Comment: Use the `FIONREAD` ioctl.

Comment: Easiest is to use a cache-buffer to read in the socket data and process from there when there is enough. In TCP, it is possible to only get only a couple of bytes from a new message that was attached to the previous message because TCP sends bytes in a stream, but chunked in [PDU-s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ioctl()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) with  the `FIONREAD` (`SIOCINQ`) request.

From the [tcp(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) manpage:

> The following [ioctl(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) calls return information in `value`.  The correct syntax is:
>
> ```
> int value;
> error = ioctl(tcp_socket, ioctl_type, &value);
> ```
>
> `ioctl_type` is one of the following:
>
> SIOCINQ
> Returns the amount of queued unread data in the receive buffer.  The socket must not be in LISTEN state, otherwise an error (EINVAL) is returned.  SIOCINQ is defined in <linux/sockios.h>.  Alternatively, you can use the synonymous FIONREAD, defined in <sys/ioctl.h>.
>
> ...

From the [udp(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html) manpage:

> These ioctls can be accessed using [ioctl(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html).  The correct syntax is:
>
> ```
> int value;
> error = ioctl(udp_socket, ioctl_type, &value);
> ```
>
> FIONREAD (SIOCINQ)
> Gets a pointer to an integer as argument.  Returns the size of the next pending datagram in the integer in bytes, or 0 when no datagram is pending.  Warning: Using FIONREAD, it is impossible to distinguish the case where no datagram is pending from the case where the next pending datagram contains zero bytes of data.  It is safer to use [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), or [epoll(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) to distinguish these cases.
>
> ...

The socket will be in the readable state as long as its receive buffer contains at least 1 byte in TCP, or 1 datagram in UDP.  Or, in the case of TCP, if the connection has been closed gracefully by the peer (a `FIN` packet was received), in which case a subsequent read will report 0 bytes.

Comment: Thank you! A question... you said it would return 0 if the connection was closed gracefully. Will it still return 0 if the connection was closed due to a TCP timeout?

Comment: @Anonymous1847 a read timeout won't close a TCP connection (a TCP keepalive timeout will invalidate a connection, though). But no, a timeout will not make a read return 0. A timeout is an actual error condition, so the read will return -1 instead, and set `errno` accordingly, such as `ETIMEDOUT`, `ECONNRESET`, etc.